Admin lacks permission to add firebase@flutterflow.io as editor
I have a very strange problem. I want to allow firebase@flutterflow.io domain user be added as an "Editor" to my firebase project. This is a requirement for flutter flow to work with firebase. However when I try to do that I get an error saying I don't have sufficient privileges.
So then I log into google cloud console and want to edit "domain restricted sharing" policy to allow flutterflow.io assuming it is not whitelisted. However I am seeing that "manage policy" action button is disabled and it says you need following permissions for this action, orgpolicy.policies.create, orgpolicy.policies.delete, orgpolicy.policies.update, and orgpolicy.policy.get.
This is strange since I am a superadmin and administer the domain that I am using to login. Can someone advise what could be wrong?
I have tried exploring help section and read stuff but to no avail. I have double checked that I am indeed an administrator.
